# Why does Mandrill not recognize my merge tags?

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

I am using the Mandrill API and have a simple template:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello *|name|* 
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And am using the send-template.json API from here: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-template

And when i insert my payload then the 'name' var is still not populated, any idea why?

```
{
    "key": "secret",
    "template_name": "mandrill-sunday",
    "template_content": [
        {
            "name": "example name"
        }
    ],
    "message": {
        "html": "<p>Example HTML content</p>",
        "text": "Example text content",
        "subject": "example subject",
        "from_email": "message.from_email@example.com",
        "from_name": "Example Name",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
                "name": "Recipient Name"
            }
        ],
        "headers": {
            "Reply-To": "myemail@yahoo.com"
        },
        "important": false,
        "track_opens": null,
        "track_clicks": null,
        "auto_text": null,
        "auto_html": null,
        "inline_css": null,
        "url_strip_qs": null,
        "preserve_recipients": null,
        "bcc_address": "kamil@myemail.com",
        "tracking_domain": null,
        "signing_domain": null,
        "merge": true,
        "global_merge_vars": [
            {
                "name": "merge1"
            }
        ],
        "merge_vars": [
            {
                "rcpt": "myemail@gmail.com",
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "name": "merge2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "tags": [
            "password-resets"
        ],
        "google_analytics_domains": [
            "mydomain.com"
        ],
        "google_analytics_campaign": "mandrill-sunday",
        "metadata": {
            "website": "www.mydomain.com"
        },
        "recipient_metadata": [
            {
                "rcpt": "myemail@gmail.com",
                "values": {
                    "user_id": 123456
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "async": false
}
```

But the only thing i get back in my email sent is:

```
Hello *|name|*
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Because each replacement requires two fields: its name and its contents. So your merge should become something like:

```
"vars": [
  {
     "name": "name",
     "content" : "merge2"
  }
]
```

Comment: am I the only one who thinks this is highly unconventional. Why not simple: `"mergeTagName": "mergeTageContent"`

Comment: At first it seems. But if you consider that this is JavaScript it makes more sense. The string value to the left of the colon is part of the interface definition. The string value to the right of the colon is what you pass to it.

Answer (score 4):

Have to use `global_merge_vars`

```
global_merge_vars': [{'content': 'merge1 content', 'name': 'name'}]
```

Comment: What's the difference, ours is working with global merge vars but not template content?

Answer (score 2):

There's two things that could trip you up here.

1) (as others have mentioned) Each merge variable object has two key-value pairs, name and content:

```
'global_merge_vars': [
            {
                'name': 'fullName',
                'content': 'foo bar',
            },
            {
                'name': 'email',
                'content': 'foobar@gmail.com',
            }

 ],
```

2) Make sure to set your merge language to either mailchimp or handlebars for mandrill.

```
'merge_language': 'mailchimp',
```

Source: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.python.html#method=send-template

Comment: You'd need to rework the template to *use* handlebars, though. OP's syntax in the question, `*|name|* `, is *not* handlebars.

Comment: That's mailchimp's template language. I'll edit and default to mailchimp

Answer (score 0):

I just tried accepted answer with SMTP header and it did not work. (I'm writing in Ruby (on Rails) here)

```
headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = [
  {name: 'name', content: 'pieter'}
].to_json
```

Though most straightforward way works. Maybe they changed something or SMTP headers works differently?.. This works:

```
headers['X-MC-MergeVars'] = {
  name: 'pieter'
}.to_json
```